# Vertical bar chart axis labels with libchart

Tags: php, charts

I create VerticalBarCharts by libchart and it look like this:
[image]

But client want add labels on the left axis(red arrow). I searched for solution in lib api but didn't find it. Is there way to do this?
Or if not, what library can give the same functional? (draw chart images on server side)

Comment: use the horizontal chart? http://naku.dohcrew.com/libchart/pages/introduction/sample2.html or you could use the javascript google charts.

Comment: As I wrote need server side charts. Horizontal tab is not what needed, on the left axis should be labels for some interval of values. For example, from 20 to 40 should have 'Disagree' label.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but did you find a way to do that?

Comment: Actually it was so long time ago and know I don't remember.. But I guess I hadn't found the solution.